# highcharts ampersand

Tags: highcharts, html-entities, ampersand

How can I make the ampersand display properly under the first set of bars/columns in this chart:

http://jsfiddle.net/VxbrK/2/

It should be 'Apples & Oranges' not 'Apples `&amp;` Oranges'.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set useHTML as true for labels.

```
xAxis: {
                labels:{
                    useHTML:true
                }
            },
```

Answer (score 1):

The html entities display is seriously bugged:
http://forum.highcharts.com/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=7299&p=35653

In my experience I found that the better workaround is to use the unicode escape sequence instead of entities.

Answer (score 0):

If you decide to go for the unicode escape sequence, keep in mind entities like `&#233;` won't directly translate to `/u0233` but to `/u00E9` (the hexidecimal value). the conversion list can be found here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters.